# Postgresql Select query stuck in execution

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I am using PostgreSQL version 11. It contains millions of data in it. Everything, including Insert, and Update, is working normal, but when I run a select query with some filters, it gets stuck and does not respond even after *10 minutes*.

I am using this simple query to test but still, it is getting stuck.

```
select tweet_id, user_id 
from "TweetsData" 
where lid_id=1 and tweet_time<='2020-06-09 09:00:00' 
order by tweet_time desc limit 10
```

Even I am not getting **Explain Analyze** output for this query.

Here is the output of **EXPLAIN**

```
Limit  (cost=2053991.46..2053992.62 rows=10 width=43)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=2053991.46..3462030.09 rows=12068060 width=43)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=2052991.43..2068076.51 rows=6034030 width=43)
              Sort Key: tweet_time DESC
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "TweetsData"  (cost=0.00..1922598.21 rows=6034030 width=43)
                    Filter: ((tweet_time <= '2020-06-09 09:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (lid_id = 1))
```

Kindly help me on how I can solve this issue? This is very critical.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you indexed the column?

Comment: which column? tweet_time? 
I did not index it. I am using this DB for 5 to 6 months. This issue started today.

Comment: Try to run only `EXPLAIN` - even if it is only an estimated plan: how many rows should the query return ?

Comment: @pifor the output of ```EXPLAIN``` is shown in question, i have editted question with explain query output.

Comment: OK the query returns only 10 rows because of `LIMIT 10` but it is estimated to scan about 12M of rows in parallel mode.

Comment: @pifor you are right, it has to scan over 12M rows, but till now it was not an issue, why this is happening now?

Comment: Not enough information to answer here. Something has changed but what ? How long does a similar query takes normally ? With what number of rows ? Do you have tools that can keep track of performance like pgbadger or powa ? I suggest also  to check `pg_stat_activity` (but unlikely that there is locking situation) and PostgreSQL log. Is autovacuum running OK in the last days especially for this table ?

Comment: @pifor similiar query should take normally less than 2 to 3 seconds. Data is about 23M. it should return nearly 3 lac rows if we remove limit. Moreover i do not have any tool to keep track of performance. In ```pg_stat_activity``` there is locking situation ```LWLock```
autovaccum is turned on in settings, but how to check if it run for specific table or not.?

Comment: This is not a performance-related issue, Issue is with a select query. It stuck and do not respond while insert queries are working normally. why is that? 
i have been using same queries for so long.

Comment: Please edit your post and add output of `select pid, query, state, wait_event_type, wait_event, pg_blocking_pids(pid) as blocked_by from pg_stat_activity where wait_event is not null`;

Comment: This **is** a performance related issue. ( even worse: it is a data-modelling issue) Due to the lack on indexes, the planner can only choose one plan: scan **all** the rows, sort them, filter them, and pick the top-10 rows.

Comment: You can get last autovaccum date with `select relname, last_autovacuum from pg_stat_all_tables where relname="TweetsData"`;

Answer (score 0):

Without a usable index, the planner can only choose one plan: scan **all** the rows, sort them, filter them, and pick the top-10 rows. That means: fetching 12M records from disk, just to obtain 10 result tuples. An indexed access will only require fetching x*10 pages fom disk. (with x between 0.1 and maybe a few dozen)

Only a single index (on the timestamp) is used here (the columns names are slightly different) :

---

```
select version();

\d tweets_created_at_idx

        -- Before jun 9
explain analyse
select id, user_id
from tweets
where sucker_id = 507                   -- low-cardinality condition
and created_at < '2020-06-09 09:00:00'  -- about 7M records
order by created_at desc
limit 10;

        -- After jun 9
explain analyse
select id, user_id
from tweets
where sucker_id = 507                   -- low-cardinality condition
and created_at >= '2020-06-09 09:00:00' -- about 5K records
order by created_at desc
limit 10;
```

---

Output:

---

```
                                                version                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit
(1 row)

           Index "public.tweets_created_at_idx"
   Column   |           Type           | Key? | Definition 
------------+--------------------------+------+------------
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | yes  | created_at
btree, for table "public.tweets"

                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..1.65 rows=10 width=24) (actual time=0.059..0.079 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using tweets_created_at_idx on tweets  (cost=0.43..853049.60 rows=6995588 width=24) (actual time=0.052..0.071 rows=10 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (created_at < '2020-06-09 09:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone)
         Filter: (sucker_id = 507)
 Planning Time: 0.339 ms
 Execution Time: 0.102 ms
(6 rows)

                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..11.98 rows=10 width=24) (actual time=0.035..0.053 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using tweets_created_at_idx on tweets  (cost=0.43..6604.02 rows=5720 width=24) (actual time=0.034..0.050 rows=10 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (created_at >= '2020-06-09 09:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone)
         Filter: (sucker_id = 507)
 Planning Time: 0.143 ms
 Execution Time: 0.067 ms
(6 rows)
```

---

Output on a RaspberryPi B **(about ten times as slow)**:

---

```
                                                          version                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.5 on armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 32-bit
(1 row)

Did not find any relation named "tweets_created_at_idx".
               Index "public.tweets_du_idx"
   Column   |           Type           | Key? | Definition 
------------+--------------------------+------+------------
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | yes  | created_at
 user_id    | bigint                   | yes  | user_id
btree, for table "public.tweets"

                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..7.16 rows=10 width=24) (actual time=0.337..0.481 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using tweets_du_idx on tweets  (cost=0.43..4796963.78 rows=7126207 width=24) (actual time=0.322..0.428 rows=10 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (created_at < '2020-06-09 09:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone)
         Filter: (sucker_id = 507)
 Planning Time: 4.272 ms
 Execution Time: 0.828 ms
(6 rows)

                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..7.75 rows=10 width=24) (actual time=0.202..0.435 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using tweets_du_idx on tweets  (cost=0.43..12876.25 rows=17588 width=24) (actual time=0.186..0.380 rows=10 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (created_at >= '2020-06-09 09:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone)
         Filter: (sucker_id = 507)
 Planning Time: 8.428 ms
 Execution Time: 0.784 ms
(6 rows)
```